# Get custom taxonomy list for products post type by other taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have this situation that I'm trying to figure out.

I've created a custom product taxonomy named cities, each product can belong to a **product_cat** taxonomy and/or **city** taxonomy.

On a shop product category I want to create a widget that displays available cities for current category.

I've managed to do this but it's not a optimized code that I'm looking for.

right now this is how it looks like

```
// get current category
$cate = get_queried_object();
         $catID = $cate->term_id;
         $catID;
          $link = get_term_link( $catID, 'product_cat' );

         $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'term'     =>  $catID
            )
          );

         $products = new WP_Query( $args );

         $cities = array();

         foreach ($products->posts as $product) {
          echo('<ul>');
           $terms = get_the_terms($product->ID,'city');
           if (is_array($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
              if (!in_array($term->slug, $cities)) {
                $cities[] = $term->slug;
                $city_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'city' );
                echo "<li><a href='{$link}city/{$term->slug}'>{$term->name}</a></li>";
              }
            }
          }
          echo('</ul>');
        }
```

This if not by the WP_Query function I think it could be done by a SQL query but this is out of my league.

Comment: On your business logic, please elaborate: You describe that a product can belong to a category _and_ a city, but are cities children of categories? If you want a list of cities in the category, it helps to know if you're looking at the posts or the categories for that list. ALso, it wasn't clear in your question... what about the code you provided isn't working?

Comment: "that displays available cities for current category" There is no easy way to link taxonomies that I'm aware of

Comment: unfortunately even with mysql it will be a expensive query so just use caching. If you will be updating other elements of the page regularly object cache the query above, if not cache the page.

Comment: @Practically the code above is working, I'm trying to make it more optimized, the cities aren't children of categories

Comment: @David thanks for the information too bad so right now I'll leave it as it and make use of caching